# Filtering by analytic function results without subquery or subtable

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, netsuite

I'm working on Netsuite project which has limited SQL capabilites. It's difficult to test as I am basically guessing the SQL they are building in their GUI.

I'd like to filter the results of a query to the results with a negative value of a culmative sum.

Is the following a valid PL/SQL construct (barring any small syntactical errors)?

```
 SELECT SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED
    PRECEDING) AS "sum" FROM table WHERE sum < 0
```

Secondly, due to limitations in Netsuite, is the following a valid construct?

```
 SELECT SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED 
    PRECEDING) AS "sum" FROM table WHERE SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY itemid
    ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) < 0
```

Oracle's documentation suggests that neither of these are valid and filtering an analytic function should be done via subquery but some google groups and other websites suggest otherwise. Most however are using RANK() and DENSE_RANK() functions in their examples which may function differently.

Comment: Aggregate functions can't be used in `WHERE` clause. Neither can aliases. For aliases, just do this in subquery (or repeat entire operation - better not), and for filtering on `SUM(amount)` simply group your records and put this in `HAVING` clause.

Comment: You can't filter the result of an Analytic Function using WHERE or HAVING (because it's calculated **after** aggregation/HAVING), you must put it in a Derived Table.

Comment: "but some google groups and other websites suggest otherwise" - If they are really suggesting this they are wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To filter in on the result of analytic functions you have to use inline views (subqueries in the from clause).

For example, your query might look like:

```
select  *
from    (
            select  itemid,
                    date,
                    sum(amount) over (
                                        partition by itemid
                                        order by date
                                        rows between unbounded preceding
                                                 and current row
                                     ) as run_sum
            from    table
        )
where   run_sum < 0
```

This will show all items, and the associated dates, on which the running sum for that item was less than zero (if there are any such dates for a given item).